# Why is my Lagrange polynomial not working?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

(Hi! I am a G11 IB Math AA SL student and I am really struggling to understand what I am doing wrong. First time using this site, so please forgive me if I mess up ).

**My set of data is:**
{{3.8, 1.69},{4, 1.24},{4.2, 0.33},{4.4, 0.294}{4.6, 0.347},{4.8, 0.487},{5, 0.286},{5.2, 0.898},{5.4, -0.58}}

I used [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyHP3.png) to find the Ls for each point

This is what I got

$$L(3.8) = x^8 - 37.6x^7 + 617.68x^6 - 5790.4x^5 + 33879.6304x^4 - 126692.68864x^3 + 295695.78163x^2 - 393821.36524x + 229154.36544$$

and etc.

I multiplied each $L$ by the $y$ value of its $x$ point. For example,    $1.69 L(3.8)$

Then, I added all the $L$'s together and simplified the equation [until I got this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLXQ8.png)

I cannot find where I did a mistake and every online calculator gives me the same equation!
Yet, if I substitute the value 4 into the formula, for example, I do not get 1.24.

Please help!!

Edit: The formula:
$-(1.7625\times10^2)x^8 + (6.4585\times10^3)x^7 - (1.0337\times10^5)x^6 + (9.4389\times10^5)x^5 - (5.3777\times10^6)x^4 + (1.9577\times10^7)x^3 - (4.4468\times10^7)x^2 + (5.7621\times10^7)x - (3.2612\times10^7)$

Edit:
Thank you to everyone who tried to help me!! Just an update - I gave up, nothing seems to work. I am going to model the function in a different way.

Comment: What *do* you get when you substitute in the value $4$? (in other words is this just a rounding error?)  As far as I can see you have the right formula, but I can't possible check your arithmetic.

Comment: Your final polynomial is basically correct but not accurate enough. If you keep enough significant digits ($15$ should be enough) when computing the polynomial, it should give $1.24$ for an input of $4$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician when I substitute 4, I get 25984.0

Comment: @quasi I didn't think of that... But I get 25984.0 when I substitute 4 - isn't that a little too big of a difference?

Comment: Please write the formula in the body of the question instead of inserting the pictures.

Comment: Yes, way too far off. Check your substitution. I get 1,24 with high accuracy.

Comment: @user - I will do this immediately - sorry, I am new to this site

Comment: @quasi Sorry, what do you mean when you say "I get 1,24 with high accuracy" - did I substitute it incorrectly?

Comment: Either the polynomial you used for the substitution is not what you show in your picture, or you made an error in performing the substitution. Either way, there's no mathematical issue here.

Comment: You show two polynomials. The second one is the final one.

Comment: @quasi Yes, I am using the last polynomial and I substitute x=4 into it. Thank you so much for your help! I have no idea why I keep on getting the wrong answer even though I do the same calculation over and over again, but I am glad that this is not a mathematical error or a rule I don't know about. Genuinely, tysm!!!

Comment: @quasi What software did you use to get your answer?

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate+%7B%7B3.8%2C+1.69%7D%2C%7B4%2C+1.24%7D%2C%7B4.2%2C+0.33%7D%2C%7B4.4%2C+0.294%7D%7B4.6%2C+0.347%7D%2C%7B4.8%2C+0.487%7D%2C%7B5%2C+0.286%7D%2C%7B5.2%2C+0.898%7D%2C%7B5.4%2C+-0.58%7D%7D) gives a slightly different polynomial.

Comment: I used Maple, and I set the precision to $15$ digits. $15$ is enough, $10$ is not accurate enough (with $10$ it gives $1.20$). If I set the precision to $50$ digits, the result is ridiculously accurate.

Comment: The Maple command Digits$=15$ sets the number of significant digits for all decimal calculations (e.g., when computing the polynomial and for doing  the substitution).

Comment: @quasi I am doing the calculations by hand (+ TI 84) because I do not have professional software - what would the "setting precision to 15 digits" mean for me? Because every answer than I get is a 4 digit number and I have tried many online calculators as well

Comment: You will lose accuracy, but it shouldn't be as far off as what you reported.

Comment: @quasi Okay, then there must be something wrong with how I am calculating it. You are simply substituting 4 instead of x, right? and you get 1.24?

Comment: Using precision set to $15$ digits: for $x=4$, I get $1.2400047$.

Comment: @quasi hmm, okay, I will figure out what is going on... Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The program Maxima is a free CAS (Computer Algebra System). It's not as nice as Maple, but it's free.

Comment: @quasi thank you for the suggestion - I am trying to figure out how the software works rn but it is a lot more complicated than what I am used to :)

Comment: @Moo How did you get this equation? And how come your polynomial only goes to the power of 7 if there are 9 values?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's the Maple session I used:

[image]

and here's a Maxima session for the same task:

[image]

Comment: That's extremely helpful! I gave up, but it's nice to know that the math was not wrong. Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is already given. I would like add that the problem of accuracy of numerical calculus is more general. For example we have the same difficulty with the direct method of linear solving:
$$y(x_k)=a_0+a_1x_k+a_2(x_k)^2+...+a_i(x_k)^i+...a_8(x_k)^8 \qquad\text{for }\quad k=1\text{ to }k=9.$$
The matrix linear calculus gives the values of the coefficients $a_i$ :
$$\big[a_i\big]=\big[(x_k)^{i}\big]^{-1}\big[y_k\big]\qquad\text{with }\quad i=0\text{ to }8\quad\text{and }k=1\text{ to }9.$$
The result is :

[image]

RMSE : Root Mean Square Error.

If we keep less digits of the coefficients $a_i$ the LRMSE increases.

This is quite not visible on the graph if the number of digits is higher than 12. With less digits the error becomes more and more evident.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*This a not an answer.*

The exact values of the coefficients of the interpolating polynomial are
$$\left\{-\frac{32611801819}{1000},\frac{4840183012739}{84000},-\frac{24901762709}{
   560},\frac{112762077761}{5760},-\frac{2065046621}{384},\frac{1087353055}{1152}
   ,-\frac{39694625}{384},\frac{6510125}{1008},-\frac{236875}{1344}\right\}$$